# TDD Swift Unit testing a function with no inputs

Tags: swift

I'm playing with Unit testing in Swift. I can mock and test most of my functions. However I'm struggling with this one (it's for a quiz):

```
public func getQuestionSetStats() -> (numberOfQs: Int, answered: Int, totalCorrect: Int, totalWrong: Int)? {
    guard questionSet != nil && questionSet!.count > 0 else {return nil}
    let number = questionSet!.count
    let answered = questionSet!.filter{ $0.answerGiven != nil && $0.answerGiven ?? 0 >= 0 }.count
    let correct = Array ( zip(questionSet!.map{ Int( $0.question.solution) }, questionSet!.map{ $0.answerGiven }) )
    let correctAnswers = correct.filter{ $0.0 == ( ($0.1 ?? 10) + 1)}.count
    let wrong = number - correctAnswers
    return (numberOfQs: number, answered: answered, totalCorrect: correctAnswers, totalWrong: wrong)
}
```

This basically returns the state of my quiz manager for display by some view controller.

Since the vars are very much caught up in the state of the quiz manager I don't know how to unit test this function without setting up a whole state for the function - what is the best approach to do this.

Comment: It looks to me like the only thing you need to set up is the `questionSet` property?

Comment: Irrespective of that (there may be n properties), how do I set up the n properties? Inject into the function?

Comment: I don’t know what those n properties are so I can’t answer that but generally speaking if you have to many dependencies it might be good reason to refactor your code and create classes/structs with narrower and more well defined responsibilities